# How do i get the header value of the cell matching today?

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I have following table, that i want to get the header value(T1, T2, T3...) of the cell matching today's date. These dates are formatted as DD-MM-YYYY.

I tried using VLOOKUP to find the correct cell first, but that returns me a wrong date. Tried on 2023-04-7 but it returns me 21-03-2023.

```
=VLOOKUP(TODAY(), A3:U20, 2)
```

How do i do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
=tocol(index(if(A3:U20=today(),A2:U2,)),1)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.